# Hibernate & JPA "mappedBy" vs. owner of the relation & cascades

Tags: java, sql, hibernate

### Background

Suppose we have bidirectional `OneToOne` relationship. 
There are `User` and `Address` entity. `User` has many `Address`es.

```
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS hibernate_sequence;
CREATE TABLE users (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE addresses (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT fk_addresses_user_id REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

and

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  //mappings
  private Address address;
}

@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  //mapings
  private User user;
}
```

### Disclaimer:

I'm using `OneToOne` as an example but the question is about relations in general so the right approach is valid for `ManyToMany` as well.

TL;DR - the question is about using `mappedBy<->relation owner<->cascades<->managing other side in setters` in general

### Questions:

1. In database there should be user_id in address table table, right? Who is the owner of the relation then?
2. In entities: which one should have mappedBy - (`User` or `Address`) / (Owner or Inverse)?

   - This link: https://coderanch.com/t/595728/databases/Newbie-Hibernate-OneToMany-owning-side states: "Note that the mappedBy automatically makes the relationship the inverse or non-owning side." so `Address` should have mappedBy
   - While in this link: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ `Post` (`User` in my example) have mappedBy to `PostDetails` (`Address` in my example)
   - Javadoc: https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html#mappedBy() says "The field that owns the relationship" so `User` owns the relation, and therefore `Address` should have mappedBy (`CustomerRecord` in JavaDoc)
   - But hibernate documentation: http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.4/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#associations-one-to-one-bidirectional the parent `Phone` (`Person` in my example) has mappedBy to `PhoneDetails` (`Address`)
3. On which side (`User` or `Address`) / (mappedBy or inverse-side) the `@OneToOne(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH})` should be placed?
4. And last question: which of the entities should manage the relation like this:

```
public void addAddress(Address address) {
  if (address != null) {
    address.addUser(this);
  }
  this.addresses.add(address);
}

public void removeAddress(Address address) {
  if (address != null) {
    address.removeUser(this);
  }
  this.addresses.remove(address);
}

public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
  return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.addresses);
}
```

the (`User` or `Address`) / (mappedBy or inverse-side)?

- This link: https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/ shows the approach listed above (where the parent, `User` in my example, manages the relation)
- But here: https://www.quora.com/What-is-the-purpose-of-mapped-by-element-in-OneToMany-annotation-in-Hibernate Vlad says: "it’s always good practice if the child side, where the Foreign Key is located, controls the association", so the Address should "controll the relation" (exactly the opposite)?

Moreover - look at theese two links:

- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html - here CustomerRecord has mappedBy
- https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToMany.html - but here Customer has mappedBy!

Thank you in advance

PS. Previous version of my question was using `OneToMany` as an example, but because inverse - `ManyToOne` does not have mapped by I changed it to `OneToOne` which better shows the problem

Answer (score 6):

### Table relationships vs. entity relationships

In a relational database system, there are three types of table relationships:

- one-to-many (via a Foreign Key column)
- one-to-one (via a shared Primary Key)
- many-to-many (via a link table with two Foreign Keys referencing two separate parent tables)

So, a `one-to-many` table relationship looks like this:

[image: one-to-many table relationship]

Note that the relationship is based on the `post_id` Foreign Key column in the child `post_comment` table.

So, the Foreign Key column is the single source of truth when it comes to managing a `one-to-many` table relationship.

Now, let's take a bidirectional JPA entity relationship that maps the `one-to-many` table relationship we saw previously:

[image: Bidirectional One-To-Many entity association]

If you take a look at the diagram above, you can see that there are two ways to manage this relationship.

In the `Post` entity, you have the `comments` collection:

```
@OneToMany(
    mappedBy = "post",
    cascade = CascadeType.ALL,
    orphanRemoval = true
)
private List<PostComment> comments = new ArrayList<>();
```

And, in the `PostComment`, the `post` association is mapped as follows:

```
@ManyToOne(
    fetch = FetchType.LAZY
)
@JoinColumn(name = "post_id")
private Post post;
```

So, you have two sides that can change the entity association:

- By adding an entry in the `comments` child collection, a new `post_comment` row should be associated with the parent `post` entity via its `post_id` column.
- By setting the `post` property of the `PostComment` entity, the `post_id` column should be updated as well.

Because there are two ways to represent the Foreign Key column, you must define which is the source of truth when it comes to translating the association state change into its equivalent Foreign Key column value modification.

### MappedBy (a.k.a the inverse side)

The `mappedBy` attribute tells that the `@ManyToOne` side is in charge of managing the Foreign Key column, and the collection is used only to fetch the child entities and to cascade parent entity state changes to children (e.g., removing the parent should also remove the child entities).

> It's called the *inverse side* because it references the child entity property that manages this table relationship.

### Synchronize both sides of a bidirectional association

Now, even if you defined the `mappedBy` attribute and the child-side `@ManyToOne` association manages the Foreign Key column, you still need to synchronize both sides of the bidirectional association.

The best way to do that is to add these two utility methods:

```
public void addComment(PostComment comment) {
    comments.add(comment);
    comment.setPost(this);
}

public void removeComment(PostComment comment) {
    comments.remove(comment);
    comment.setPost(null);
}
```

The [`addComment`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) and [`removeComment`](https://vladmihalcea.com/jpa-hibernate-synchronize-bidirectional-entity-associations/) methods ensure that both sides are synchronized. So, if we add a child entity, the child entity needs to point to the parent and the parent entity should have the child contained in the child collection.

Comment: Vlad,
Let's say this is [article 1](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
and this is [article 2](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)
In article 1 `Post` has `mappedBy` to `PostDetails` while in article 2 `Tag` has mappedBy to `Post `. Article 2 seems to be correct while Article 1 seems to be incorrect. Am I wrong? If yes - could you point me to the article (or chapter of your book) that explains why?

Comment: Moreover: in [article 1](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) entity that has `mappedBy` is managing the relation (`setDetails`) while in [article 2](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) entity that doesn't have `mappedBy` is managing the relation (`addTag` / `removeTag`) are both approaches valid?

Comment: Both articles are correct. You are comparing a one-to-one association to a many-to-many one, hence your confusion. A many to many association is between 2 parents while the one-to-one is a parent-child one. MappedBy is just a flag marking the source of truth in a bidirectional association. That's it and it has nothing to do with cascading.

Comment: So what you're saying is:
a) The "Owner" of the relation is the entity which table containt ForeignKey
b) The "Parent" of the relation is up to the business
c) "Parent" and "Owner" are completly orthogonal and unrelated to each other,
Hence:
1) I can have cascades on both "mappedBy" and inverse side? 
and
2) cascades are related to "Parent"
and
3) cascases are not related to "Owner" of the relation (mappedBy)?
Am I 100% Correct?

Comment: No, that's not what I said.

Comment: I'm sorry, that is what I understood.
Which of my points are wrong? or all of them?

Comment: 1. MappedBy = Inverse. 2. Yes. 3. For parent-child associations, yes, for manytomany, no.

Comment: Vlad,
In [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) you wrote:

"The Post entity is the parent, while the PostDetails is the child association because the Foreign Key is located in the post_details database table."

1) And above you wrote: "The mappedBy attribute marks the side of a bidirectional association which does not own the association".

Therefore in One2One relation "mappedBy" should be located in Parent. 
Is that correct?

Comment: 2) Then you wrote "On the other hand, cascading entity state transitions only makes sense from parents to child entities." 

Therefore in One2One relation CASCADE should be placed in Parent, Right? So it is technically not "on the other hand" but exactly `next to the mappedBy`. Is that correct?

Comment: Exactly. Place CascadeType next to MappedBy. That means that "this" entity is the Parent (=non-owner, defined by MappedBy) but cascades certain state changes to it's child (owner).

Answer (score 4):

This is what I have learnt so far.

If I'm mistaken to any of the points - please let me know in comments, and I edit the answer.

## Database

#### Owner of the relation

`According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55400561/4267927)

> Basically, the owner is address, as it's the owner who holds the reference.

So the "`owner`" of relation in database is entity with foreign key - `Address` in case of OneToOne/OneToMany.
Moreover - it seems that in the same time "`owner`" of the database relation is the `Child` in Hibernate relation - but I need confirmation for this

## OneToOne

#### Parent/Child

According to [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetoone-relationship-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

> The Post entity is the parent, while the PostDetails is the child association because the Foreign Key is located in the post_details database table

So `User` is the `Parent` and `Address` is the `Child` here (because `Address` holds foreign key)

#### mappedBy

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55401912/4267927)

> The mappedBy attribute marks the side of a bidirectional association which does not own the association. Usually, that's the side which does not have the Foreign Key.

So `mappedBy` should be placed in `User`, because `foreign key` is in `Address`. 
In seems that in `@OneToOne` `mappedBy` should be always placed in `Parent` (entity not holding the foreign key)

#### JoinColumn

It seems that `JoinColumn` in `OneToOne` must be always placed in `Child` (since it holds foreign key)

#### Cascades

According to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55401912/4267927)

> cascading entity state transitions only makes sense from parents to child entities.

So `cascades` in `OneToOne` should be always done in `Parent`, so - according to previous links - `User` in this example

#### set utility method

I'm not sure but it seems that utility setter should be placed in `User`.

Is it always placed in the `Parent`?

#### Outcome

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS hibernate_sequence;
CREATE TABLE users (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE addresses (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL UNIQUE CONSTRAINT fk_addresses_user_id REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

```java
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, optional = false, orphanRemoval = true)
  private Address address;

  public void setAddress(Address address) {
    if (address != null) {
      address.setUser(this);
    }
    this.address = address;
  }
}

@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @OneToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
}
```

## OneToMany

#### Parent/Child

It seems to be the same as with `OneToOne`, so `User` is the `Parent` and `Address` is the `Child` (because it has foreign key), but I'm not 100% sure...

#### mappedBy

In [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-map-a-onetomany-association-with-jpa-and-hibernate/) `mappedBy` is placed in `Parent` (but I'm not sure if this is the rule of thumb though)

#### JoinColumn

It seems that `JoinColumn` in `OneToMany` must be always placed in `Child` (since it holds foreign key)

#### Cascades

In above article `cascades` are also placed in `Parent` (but I'm not sure if this is the rule of thumb as well)

#### add/remove utility methods

In above article `utility methods` are also placed in `Parent` (but I'm not sure if this is the rule of thumb as well)

#### Outcome

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS hibernate_sequence;
CREATE TABLE users (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE addresses (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_addresses_user_id REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
);
```

```java
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy = "user", cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, orphanRemoval = true)
  private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

  public void addAddress(Address address) {
    if (address != null) {
      address.setUser(this);
    }
    this.addresses.add(address);
  }

  public void removeAddress(Address address) {
    this.addresses.remove(address);
    if (address != null) {
      address.setUser(null);
    }
  }

  public Set<Address> getAddresses() {
    return Collections.unmodifiableSet(this.addresses);
  }
}

@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne(fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
  @JoinColumn(name = "user_id")
  private User user;
}
```

## ManyToMany

#### Parent/Child

According to [this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/the-best-way-to-use-the-manytomany-annotation-with-jpa-and-hibernate/)

> A typical many-to-many database association includes two parent tables

So both `User` and `Address` are `Parents`

#### mappedBy

In the same article Vlad wrote:

> The mappedBy attribute of the posts association in the Tag entity marks that, in this bidirectional relationship, the Post entity own the association

Therefore here is the eception, because we don't have one `Parent`.
It is not clear to me what Vlad means exactly by "own", but if `User` "owns" the relation, `mappedBy` **must be placed in** `Address`,

#### JoinTable

It seems that `JoinTable` must be always placed in entity that "owns" the relation, so `User` in this case.

Am I right?

#### Cascades

According to the same article `cascades` should be always placed in "owner" defined above, so `User` in this case.

Also important thing to notice is that we can not use `REMOVE` cascade

#### add/remove utility methods

It seems that `add/remove utility methods` should be placed in `User`.

Is this the rule of thumb, that `utility methods` should be alway placed in entity that "owns" the relation?

#### Outcome

```sql
CREATE SEQUENCE IF NOT EXISTS hibernate_sequence;
CREATE TABLE users (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

CREATE TABLE addresses (
  id BIGINT PRIMARY KEY,
);

CREATE TABLE users_addresses (
  user_id BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_users_addresses_user_id REFERENCES users(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  address_id BIGINT NOT NULL CONSTRAINT fk_users_addresses_address_id REFERENCES addresses(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  PRIMARY KEY(user_id,address_id)
);
```

```java
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(cascade = {
      CascadeType.PERSIST,
      CascadeType.MERGE
    })
    @JoinTable(name = "post_tag",
      joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "post_id"),
      inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "tag_id")
    )
    private List<Address> addresses = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addAddress(Address address) {
      addresses.add(address);
      address.getUsers().add(this);
    }

    public void removeAddress(Address address) {
      addresses.remove(address);
      address.getUsers().remove(this);
    }
}

@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "addresses")
    private List<User> users = new ArrayList<>();
}
```

## Summary

I think this table sums it up: https://i.ibb.co/zNjZ3md/JPA-relations.png

The last thing I don't unserstand is:

- why Vlad [in this article](https://vladmihalcea.com/a-beginners-guide-to-jpa-and-hibernate-cascade-types/) in "ManyToMany" section uses `mappedBy` in `Author` ("owner") instead of `Book` (especially that it throws exception in my code)
- why in [javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javaee/7/api/javax/persistence/OneToOne.html) `mappedBy` is on `CustomerRecord` (child) not on `Customer` (but here maybe foreign key is located in Customer, so although counter intuitive - it is correct)

Answer (score 0):

> 1. In database there should be user_id in address table table, right? Who is the owner of the relation then?

1. Exactly. Basically, the owner is address, as it's the owner who holds the reference.

> 2. In entities: which one should have mappedBy - User or Address?

`@ManyToOne` doesn't even have the attribute mappedBy. It's present only on xToMany annotations.

Your mapping should be:

```
@Table(name = "users")
public class User {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @OneToMany(mappedBy="user", cascade = ...) // atenttion, this refer the attribute name as opposed to the column name
  private Set<Address> addresses = new HashSet<>();
}

@Table(name = "addresses")
public class Address {

  @Id
  @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE)
  private Long id;

  @ManyToOne
  @JoinColumn(name="user_id") // the name is optional if you refer to the PK
  private User user;
}
```

> On which side (User or Address?) the @ManyToMany(cascade = {CascadeType.MERGE, CascadeType.DETACH, CascadeType.REFRESH}) should be placed?
>
> And last question: which of the entities should manage the relation like this:

In this case, you want to handle User, and then JPA handles Address automatically. 
Therefore, the cascade would be on User.
On this side (OneToMany), you probably also want to add `orphanRemoval = true`.

---

*Trying to adjust after clarification...*

About the support, JPA supports cascading from both sides, ok?!
From where you should use it depends on your domain.
You are supposed to use it on the Entity which you use on entityManager operations, for instance: `em.persist(user)` or `em.merge(address)`.
Really, depends on how your code is.

In this specify case, it seems it makes more sense to leave on User. I suppose you have an User CRUD, which also includes address.

In this case, it makes sense when you create or remove an User, then its addresses are created/remove together.

On the other side, it wouldn't make sense to cascade from the Address. If you remove an Address, it does NOT mean that the user should be removed too.

Can you see?! You need to check your use case. The side to use it (whether oneToMany or manyToOne or ...) should be thought and decided based on your needs on that moment.

Comment: thank you for your answer. Two questions:
1) Are you sure that the side with mappedBy whould manage cascades?
2) Which of the class should set the opposite in setters: User like this like in my example or Address?

Comment: Hey! 1. Yes, JPA is capable of handling that cascading. 2. Yeah, you also need to set the user instance on you Address, exactly the way you did on `addAddress`. I think JPA could be smarter in this point

Comment: 1) I changed my main question because you were misleaded by OneToMany used in the example. I would apprieciate if you could read the new version of the question.
2) I'm aware that JPA can handle cascades, but the question is "On whcich side cascade should happed" - where mappedBy is or the inverse? There are sources that say exactly the opposite
3) Also the question is not if I should set instance but "On which side" - mappedBy is or the inverse?

Comment: Thak you for your help

Answer (score 0):

to make an association the owner, you must mark the other end as being mapped by the other.
I think the following link is the best for you question:
[How to Define Association Mappings between Entities](https://howtodoinjava.com/hibernate/how-to-define-association-mappings-between-hibernate-entities/)

Comment: It is recommended to add the code snippet as part of your answer along with any external link.