# How to model multiple @OneToOne relations with cascade?

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, kotlin

I have this model, where one company has one contact and one director. I have the cascade on the Company at the moment. But according to this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55401912/10554617), this is a code smell and the cascade should be on the parents, on Contact and User. I tried putting the cascade attribute on the parents but I could not save the entities using Spring CrudRepository. Is this a valid model or is it really a code smell?

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "contacts")
class Contact(
        var name: String = "",
        var residence: String = "",
        var phone: String = "",
        var email: String = "",

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "contact")
        var company: Company? = null
) : BaseEntity() {

@Entity
@Table(name = "users")
class User(
        var email: String = "",
        var fullName: String = "",

        @OneToOne(mappedBy = "director")
        var company: Company? = null
) : BaseEntity() {

@Entity
@Table(name = "companies")
class Company(
        val companyCode: String = "",
        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], optional = false)
        var director: User? = null,

        @OneToOne(cascade = [CascadeType.ALL], optional = false)
        var contact: Contact? = null
) : BaseEntity() {
```

Comment: It's a functional problem more than a technical question. Think about what's logical to do in your application. First, is it normal that a user can only be the director of one company? If not, it shouldn't be a OneToOne. Same for the contact: is it normal to have a single contact for a whole company? Now, when you create a company, will you use an existing user as its director, or will you create a new user in the same operation than the one used to create the company?

Comment: If you delete a company, should its director die at the same time and disappear from your application, or should it just stay there, as a user who is not director of any company anymore? Start with no cascade at all, unless an entity is an integral part of a parent one.

Comment: Yes, the director and the contact information are tied to the company. If I delete the director, I should delete the company with the information. If I delete the company, the director should be deleted too.

Comment: Then you can set cascade delete on the two sides of the association.

Comment: As I have it now? or should I put the cascade to Company attributes which I tried but I couldnt persist the relationship. After I tried to save the newly created Director with a Company, I got an error.

Comment: No. Currently you have a cascade ALL on one side, and no cascade at all on the other side. If you want to persist a company automatically when you persist a user, then there should be a cascade persist on User.company: the persist operation on the user csacades to its company.

Comment: Ah, I see .. and about the code smell, what do you think about that? Is this code a code smell? I wanted to use that advice but could not remove the cascade from the child (the company)

Comment: I don't really understand why you would name the company "the child". The contact and the director belong to the company, so I would rather refer to the company as the parent. But anyway, that doesn't matter: if the cascade is what you want, then use it. What would be a terrible code small would be to have a cascade on the many side of a ManyToXxx association. Deleting, for example, a customer of a company would try to delete the company, although it's obviously referenced by other customers.

Comment: because the company entity has the foreign keys of other tables, therefore it should be the child, or am i not understanding that correctly?

Comment: _"one company has one contact and one director"_ would mean that the company is the parent. _"the company entity has the foreign keys of other tables"_ you mix different concepts here. _"If I delete the director, I should delete the company with the information."_ That doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Basically, the lifecycle of director has to be tied to one company only, if the company is gone, director has to be gone too and vice versa. Could you please elaborate on the parent child thing? Thought that if a table holds foreign key, it's a child of the entity which foreign key points to.